# How would I implement recursion in this code?

Tags: python, recursion

I need help. Could someone show me how these lines of code would be implemented recursively?

I don't fully grasp the meaning of recursive.

```
def nextDay(year, month, day):
    """Simple version: assume every month has 30 days"""
    if day < 30:
        return year, month, day + 1
    else:
        if month == 12:
            return year + 1, 1, 1
        else:
            return year, month + 1, 1

def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    counter = 0
    while not (year1==year2 and month1==month2 and day1==day2):
        year1,month1,day1 = nextDay(year1,month1,day1)
        counter += 1
    return counter
```

Comment: A recursive function is a function that calls itself. It can appear weird at first (e.g how can an object be called from itself since it is not fully defined when calling itself... ). In your case, you would have `nextDay` written somewhere *in its own definition*. Also, if an answer does what you want, consider ticking it as correct. A reputation of 1 is enough to do it. I remind you this because newcomers often forget to do so. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) That being said, welcome on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Recursive functions are most natural when the problem to be solved is recursive in shape. That's not the case here, so rewriting this code to be recursive is probably not going to be very helpful.

Comment: @AkshayLAradhya That is frankly unkind. People come here to learn, not to receive condescension that may seem fun to people who get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def nextDay(year, month, day):
    """Simple version: assume every month has 30 days"""
    if day < 30:
        return year, month, day + 1
    else:
        if month == 12:
            return year + 1, 1, 1
        else:
            return year, month + 1, 1
'''
Assumption is that date1 is less than date2
'''
def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
   if year1==year2 and month1==month2 and day1==day2: # base condition
      return 0
   else:
      y, m, d = nextDay(year1, month1, day1)
      return dateBetweenDates(y, m, d, year2, month2, day2) + 1 # check for difference between new date and final date recursively
```

Explanation:

As pointed out in comments, a recursive function is a function that calls itself.

Usually we exploit this technique by checking for a base condition. Till the base condition is not met, we strive in the direction where we are likely to get our answer.

In your case, we first check if dates are equal, if yes that means we have reached to the end and if not, we just increment our current date value (using nextDay function) and call the same function to check the difference between new date and final date.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tail recursive version:

```
def daysBetweenDates(year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2):
    def helper(yearn, monthn, dayn, counter):
        if yearn==year2 and monthn==month2 and dayn==day2:
            return counter
        else:
            y, m, d = nextDay(yearn, monthn, dayn)
            return helper(y, m, d, counter + 1)
    return helper(year1, month1, day1, 0)
```

So basically all the parameters of the helper is the variables that can change, including all extra state you would need like `counter`. As a program doing this or your while loop works exactly the same, with one exception.

Since Python doesn't do Tail Call optimization your stack will blow when there is long between the dates. This is a Python implementation [design decision done by Guido](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html) (the author) and he promotes the use of comprehensions instead. In other languages the compiled result of this and your while loop would be indistinguishable.

In the most popular CPU archs (x86 and Arm) you have support for procedures (functions without arguments or return value) so function calls with arguments are simulated by making code that uses the stack to pass arguments and return values and thus there are several standards on how this is done. A while loop doesn't exist either so it is done with compare and branch instructions (gotos) so neither feature actually is something provided by the CPUs so you can say these concepts are higher order language abstractions you can use. TCO is just a fancier implementation of some calls.